# $.ajax form submit to Google Docs using JSONP: "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery, cross-domain

**Update:** Question changed to reflect use of JSONP and new problem presented itself so I've altered the question.

### Background

- I have a form submission that I need to make to a Google Docs form

  - Unfortunately this is a hard requirement for the given situation.
- I need to create a web page as a better interface to this form (long story short: folks will be using an iPad to enter information and it needs certain UI touches that the google form doesn't have by default).
- I can make this submission via the "action" of the HTML form; however, I need to override the form submit so that so I can execute some custom coder on the client side, submit the form via Ajax, and then clear the form for a new entry.

### Goal

- When the submit button is clicked, submit the form via Ajax and do something based on the success or failure of the response.

### Problem / Question

I see the following error in the Chrome console (form key omitted);

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

How can I avoid this? Is there any way I can submit this data to the Google Form without triggering this issue?

### Code so Far

HTML page:

```
<form id="ss-form" name="googleform" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
    <!-- Fields omitted for brevity -->
    <input type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("Document Ready");
        disableFormSubmissionEvent();
        wireUpSubmitButton();
    });

        disableFormSubmissionEvent = function () {
            console.log("Disabling sumission Event");
            $('#ss-form').submit(function () {
                return false;
            });

    wireUpSubmitButton = function () {
        console.log("Wiring up submit button");
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            submitForm();
        });
```

JavaScript that attempts the form submission (form key omitted):

```
  submitForm = function (event) {
            console.log("obtaining form data");
            var thedata = $('#ss-form').serialize();
            console.log("Attempting Form Submission");
            var submissionUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/[...]/formResponse";
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                crossDomain: true,
                url: submissionUrl,
                data: thedata
            }).success(function () {
                clearForm();
                showSuccessMessage();
            }
                    )
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    showFailureMessage(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, submissionUrl);
                });
```

Comment: When the user submits that form on the Google Docs website, the response will most likely be a new HTML document that informs them about success of their submission – so logically the document comes with a Content-Type text/html. For what you want, you should rather look into whether Google offers an API for submitting documents from third-party sites.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you come up with a solution to avoid the error? The post happens just fine, its just that I actually want to completely ignore the response.

Comment: Anyone found a solution to this yet? @pocketfullofcheese: it is easy to ignore the response. Just omit the .success and .error functions altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Google doc response return an html page so there is no json / jsonp for you and it's crossdomain. My suggestion is build a proxy on your site that will submit to google doc and return json

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to suppress the error, although you still get a warning logged to the console in some browsers (no error though!)

Instead of doing a JSONP request, load an image, here is an example that I used to log an email address the user supplied to Google Forms:

```
var src = '//docs.google.com/a/MY_GOOGLE_DOCS_DOMAIN/forms/d/FORM_IDENT/formResponse?entry.INPUT_ID=' + encodeURI(emailAddress);

window.email_submit_beacon = $('<img/>', {
  'src':src
});
```

I'm not 100% sure if the window.email_submit_beacon assignment is required, but I figured it's better to force the browser to keep the image in memory so it's not unloaded before the image request completes.

Note also that I'm using a custom domain, for you the URL will probably be what you posted: 
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/FORM_IDENT/formResponse

If you want to know when the request is complete, you can just look at when the image has loaded (this is similar to how you can do image preloading with JS).